# Use js crypto frameworks or browser's Web Crypto API?

Tags: javascript, cryptojs, webcrypto-api

I want to use encryption algorithms in browser. I see two ways to do that. First, using available javascript crypto frameworks like cryptojs, sjcl, etc. or the browser's inbuilt Web Crypto API. I am confused on which one is better. Can anyone please help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: What would you achieve with browser-based encryption? What's the problem you're solving?

Comment: Without any objective requirements I can say: whatever you like. You can toss a coin and let it be decided by chance. Also, have a look at [Javascript Cryptography Considered Harmful](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/)

Comment: I have already undergone through the article. I only want to create a hash of a file and just save that hash for a future reference and that's it. I know there are problems with the browser based encryption, but in my case, it is desired.

Comment: If your use scenario is for computing hashes, then I personally would opt for Web Crypto API. As for what's better - what does better mean? Both interfaces should produce the same result for a given input if you're after hashes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because browsers are more integrated with the underlying system than any JavaScript library can be, they will provide a better guarantee of security (e.g. for random number generation).

Comment: Why the downvotes? The WebCrypto API provide better security *and performance* than pure-JavaScript implementations. Is the hate on JavaScript crypto? JavaScript isn't only websites!